# Chart generation of dynamic amount per day for multiple weeks

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I want to make a chart that can be generated from 2 given dates, a start date and end date.
I studied the chart control on msdn for some time and came up with a start. However im bumping in to some problems.

Its a chart representing a count of somthing each day of the week, possible multiple weeks.
The y axis will represent the amount, the x axis will represent the week number.

So the series are the days of the week, monday up to sunday.
And a little example to finish the explanation to let you know what i mean:
Start date: 1-1-2013
End date : 1-18-2013

Will get the info from the DB, returns per row a date.
Split the date to get the day name with DateTime.

Lets say the amount on 1-1-2013 was 26, So we got 26 rows with the date 1-1-2013.
We use DateTime to see its a tuesday and then it should be put in the chart on the serie tuesday. This for everyday and when the new week start it must not get added in the first tuesday but in the tuesday of this week.

This is the code i currently have (tests cut out)

```
        string ksubConnectionString = @"Data Source=xx.xx.x.x\xxxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxxxxxxxxx;
        User ID=xxxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxxxxxxx;";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ksubConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
        connection.Open();

        // Query for data graph
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT closedDateTime FROM kasadmin.SDIncident WHERE closedDateTime < '" + textBox2.Text + " 23:59:59.000' AND closedDateTime > '" + textBox1.Text + " 00:00:00.001' ORDER BY closedDateTime ASC";
        richTextBox1.Text = "";
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (rdr.HasRows)
        {
            List<string> ArrayDates = new List<string>();

            for (int i = 0; rdr.Read(); i++)
            {
                ArrayDates.Add(rdr.GetDateTime(0).ToString());
            }
            string[] SplittedDate;
            string[] DatetimeSplit;
            int Jaar;
            int Maand;
            int Dag;
            for (int k = 0; k <ArrayDates.Count;k++ )
            {
                SplittedDate = ArrayDates[k].Split(' ');
                DatetimeSplit = SplittedDate[0].Split('-');
                Jaar = Convert.ToInt32(DatetimeSplit[2].ToString());
                Maand = Convert.ToInt32(DatetimeSplit[1].ToString());
                Dag = Convert.ToInt32(DatetimeSplit[0].ToString());
                DateTime dt = new DateTime(Jaar, Maand, Dag);

                if (dt.DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Monday")
                {
                    this.chart1.Series[0].Points.AddY(1);
                }
                if (dt.DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Tuesday")
                {
                    this.chart1.Series[1].Points.AddY(1);
                }
                if (dt.DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Wednesday")
                {
                    this.chart1.Series[2].Points.AddY(1);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = "No rows found.";
        }

        rdr.Close();
        connection.Close();
```